# How can i convert jQuery code to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

in this jquery code i am trying to load the notes.php file to div `#inside1` which is inside the div `#panel`. now when i click div `#flip`, the div `#panel` should toggle.

i have the jquery code.
but i need this same function in java script
How can i convert it?

code:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
   $("#inside1").load("notes.php");
});
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript(; Turning this into pure JavaScript (no library) would be quite some work. Only because of the slide animation. Give me a minute. I'll show you a pure JavaScript conversion of this. It's going to be ugly.

Comment: You mean you want to reimplement this script without the use of jQuery? Then look at the jQuery source code for the functions you're using here and take out the needed parts to form a new script. *Why* would you do this though?

Comment: well, this will yield some very long js code and cross browser incompatibility may arise....

Comment: @itachi Most Definitively.

Comment: I remember my Ajax classes when I was College student, it was without jQuery, messy, fat and ugly. Now add animation management you will end up with shit load of code. If you need Vanilla style code [check this out](http://vanilla-js.com/) or your jquery source code like deceze said. But you might want to explain why you need this, maybe your issue has a different solution

Comment: @TecHunter Ha, as you can see with my code. Pure JavaScript AJAX is definitively not as bad as animations though. And there are less `cross-browser` issues.

Comment: @Shawn31313 yeah I know :) my point was jQuery is nice :D, I already upvoted your code for the effort ;)

Comment: Ha, thank you! ;P But I agree. I don't know what I would do without jQuery, or any library.

Answer (score 4):

**WARNING: UGLY CODE BELOW**

```
var DOM = function (selector) {
    this.animate = function (prop, times, callbacks) {
        var el = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
        var animate = function (element, props, time, callback) {
            callback = callback || function () {};
            time = time || 1000;
            var timers = {}, // store the different interval timers so that they can be cancelled
            calls = 0, // numbers of times the call would have been called
                nprops = 0; // number of properties
            for (var prop in props) {
                (function (prop) {
                    var edit = prop == "scrollTop" ? element : element.style;
                    var stepCounter = [],
                        customStep = props[prop],
                        curr = edit[prop],
                        lastStepPercent = curr == "" ? (prop == "opacity" ? 1 : 0) : curr,
                        measure = prop == "scrollTop" || prop == "opacity" ? "" : "px",
                        stepper = function () {
                            edit[prop] = stepCounter[0] + measure;
                            stepCounter.shift();
                        };
                    if (props[prop].constructor == Number) customStep = [props[prop]];
                    for (var step = 0, len = customStep.length; step < len; step++) {
                        var from = parseInt(lastStepPercent),
                            to = parseInt(customStep[step]),
                            small = to < from,
                            numOfSteps = small ? from - to : to - from, // get current number of frames
                            multi = 30 * Math.round(parseInt(time) / 1000),
                            by = numOfSteps / (25 + multi) * len; // the stepper number

                        if (from == to) {
                            break;
                        }
                        for (var i = from; small ? i >= to : i <= to; i += small ? -by : by) {
                            stepCounter.push(i);
                        }
                        stepCounter.push(to);
                        lastStepPercent = customStep[step];
                    }
                    stepper();
                    timers[element + prop] = setInterval(function () {
                        stepper();
                        if (stepCounter.length == 0) {
                            clearInterval(timers[element + prop]);

                            calls++;
                            if (calls == nprops) {
                                callback.call(element);
                            }
                        }
                    }, time / stepCounter.length);
                    nprops++;
                })(prop);
            }
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
            animate(el[i], prop, times, callbacks);
        };
        return new DOM(selector); // re-initiate "JavaScript class" for chaining
    }
};
var $ = function (selector) {
    return new DOM(selector);
};

window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("flip").onclick = function () {
        var panel = document.getElementById("panel");
        if (panel.style.height == 0) {
            $("#panel").animate({
                height: 100
            }, 2000); // thats kinda slow...
        } else {
            $("#panel").animate({
                height: 0
            }, 2000); // thats kinda slow...
        }
    };
    var request = window.XMLHttpRequest() ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    request.open("POST", "notes.php", true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0 /*Fixes a FF bug*/ )) {
            document.getElementById("inside1").innerHTML = request.responseText;
        }
    }
    request.send();
};
```

I used an animation function I created a while ago. Note, this might not work. This was just an basic example of how long your code could get without jQuery. It also might not do exactly what your jQuery code did. I wasn't going to spend my whole night on this but I did want to show you the code I put together really quick.

It actuallys works: http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/jm8ZR/1/

I removed the AJAX call in the example. But the animation function can get pretty buggy so please just use jQuery.

Comment: your code just reminded me of how useful jQuery is.

Comment: @Subash Yes, jQuery is pretty amazing.

Answer (score 0):

**Start after Document ready**

Instead of using the $(document).ready() you could just place your  at the bottom of the page, now it will get executed after everything before that is loaded.

**DOM element selecting**

selecting DOM element can be done using

```
 document.getElementById('someID');
```

**Click event**

the click event can be added to a div by using this

```
divTag.onclick = functionRef
```

**Sliding div**

setting new content in a div will probably be best just to change the htmlcontent, instead of sliding as this will be alot more coding.

**Loading information from php file**

The $.load() function in jquery is a shorthand for doing ajax calls, take a look here to see you can do ajax calls in vanilla javascript

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

Hope this helps enough for you can rewrite the code into vanilla javascript

Comment: First, w3schools is a terrible resource in general. Second, the code there you link to is... well... who uses IE6 anymore? Not even Google supports IE7, let alone IE6.

Comment: depending on his requirements he may or may not want to implement support for those browsers, i think a discussion about the use of it is outside the scope of this question.
Furthermore the use of w3schools is in this case as good as any online code viewer